# Copy Active Directory from production to test

Tags: active-directory, adsi

We have production and testing sites on the same server and we want to have the copy of the active directory from production and have the same copy for testing.

We know how to back up the production active directory but not sure if we can restore it to testing since they are both on the same server.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> We have production and testing sites on the same server

You can't use Active Directory Sites to segregate a production and test environment, Sites are only used for routing and replication between networks on the same domain, the database and all data is the same.